# C++ container classes

Tags: c++, containers

currently I switch from Java to C++ and this is giving me a hard time (but lots of new experience ^^). I'm writing some data-transfer-objects which contain configurations for my program. I've written some classes and now I want to have a class which behaves like a container.

**Here's a header for the container:**

```
class MyContainer{

public:
MyContainer();
virtual ~MyContainer();

Config getConfig(TypeEnum type) {
    switch (type) {
    case ATYPE:
        return config_a;
    case BTYPE:
        return config_b;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

ConfigA config_a;
    ConfigB config_b;
};
```

The configs have some data in it and are derived from another config-file.

**And here is the C++-Source:**

```
 MyContainer::MyContainer(){
  ConfigA config_a(int c = 1);
  ConfigB config_b(double b = 2.1);
  this->config_a = config_a;
  this->config_b = config_b;
}
```

There are several problems I think. But the main question for me is: 
**How can I get those configs in this container to share it to other modules of my program?** I have tried to make config_a to a pointer but I always get error-messages that these types won't match.

```
 this->config_a = &config_a; //If ConfigA config_a; was ConfigA *config_a; instead
```

If you have another minute for me then please tell me if the `getConfig`-Method could work like this.

And if there's another topic for this then please share. Thanks.

Comment: Get a good C++ book, you totally misunderstand how C++ works (which is not uncommon for java programmers)

Comment: (Avoid CPP when talking about C++ - CPP usually refers to the C pre-processor.)

Comment: @Mr.Mountain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you write `ConfigA configA` in your header, the configA is automatically allocated during the allocation of the container class. So you don't have to initialize it like following:

   ```
   ConfigA config_a(1);
   this->config_a = config_a;
   ```

   Instead, you can just do the following:

   ```
   this->config_a->value = 1;
   ```
2. There is no need to write:

   ```
   ConfigA config_a(int c = 1);
   ```

   In short words, the mentioned `int c = 1` is an operation, which:

   - allocates space on heap for temporary variable c (this may be done when entering the method as well)
   - assigns value to it, which has side effect of returning the right-hand-side value
   - the returned right-hand-side value is applied to the ConfigA constructor.

   To understand this, try the following:

   ```
   int a, b, c;
   c = (a = 2) + (b = 8);
   printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);
   ```
3. If you want to pass the configs to another modules, you can choose one of the following solutions:

   a) Accept the configs as references (the config classes have to derive from the same base class):

   ```
   ConfigA & configA = dynamic_cast<ConfigA &>(container.get_config(ATYPE));
   ```

   In this case, container shall return the configs in the following way:

   ```
   return this->configA;
   ```

   But the header shall be modified:

   ```
   Config & getConfig(TypeEnum type) { (...)
   ```

   b) Accept the configs as pointers (same as above)

   ```
   ConfigA * configA = dynamic_cast<ConfigA *>(container.get_config(ATYPE));
   ```

   In this case, container shall return the configs in the following way:

   ```
   return &(this->configA);
   ```

Finally, this is the way I would do it:

```
class ConfigA
{
private:
    int i;

public:
    int GetI() const { return i; }
    void SetI(int newI) { i = newI; }
};

class ConfigB
{
private:
    float f;

public:
    float GetF() const { return f; }
    void SetF(float newF) { f = newF; }
};

class Config
{
private:
    ConfigA configA;
    ConfigB configB;

public:
    ConfigA & GetConfigA() { return configA; }
    ConfigB & GetConfigB() { return configB; }
};

class AppContext
{
private:
    Config config;

public:
    Config & GetConfig() { return config; }
};

// Somewhere in the code

Config & config = context.GetConfig();
ConfigA & configA = config.GetConfigA();
configA.SetI(44);
```

The const-correctness is also worth mentioning, but we'll leave it as an exercise for the OP ;)

Comment: I'd hope there is a way to pass the configuration without using `dynamic_cast`. That should be a last resort, really. But +1 for trying to explain the basics.

Comment: This is why I would rather make different getters for different configs rather than return them in one generic method getting an enum as a parameter. Or better, wrap all the configs in one class with separate getters.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
ConfigA config_a(int c = 1);
```

Means a function prototype that returns ConfigA and takes an int with a default value of 1.
But if you seperate the int declaration from the expression, it will change to something else:

```
int c;
ConfigA config_a(c = 1); //  This is construction of a ConfigA object
```

I would write the constructor like this:

```
MyContainer::MyContainer(int c = 1, double d = 2.1)
 :    config_a (c), config_b (d)  //  Construct the members in the intialization line
{
}
```

If you want to share a pointer to these members, return a pointer like this:

```
ConfigA * MyContainer::GetConfigA(){return &config_a;}
ConfigB * MyContainer::GetConfigB(){return &config_b;}
```

But if you want to work with pointer members:

```
 MyContainer::MyContainer(int c = 1, double d = 2.1)
 :    pConfig_a (new ConfigA (c)), pConfig_b (new ConfigB (d))
{
}


ConfigA * MyContainer::GetConfigA(){return pConfig_a;}
ConfigB * MyContainer::GetConfigB(){return pConfig_b;}


 MyContainer::~MyContainer()
{
    delete pConfig_a;
    delete pConfig_b;
}
```